# Magento: Change the text box value onchange of select box in system.xml of custom magento extension

Tags: php, jquery, xml, magento

Please help me out of the trouble I am facing.
I have added select box `SFTP host` with values `production` and `sandbox` in my system.xml file of custom extenstion. There is one text field `SFTP port` in system.xml. I want to set the text field value on change of select box.

For example, if I select option **production** then port value in text box should appear as **22**, if I select **sandbox** then port value = **21**

My **system.xml** is

```
<ftphost translate="label">
    <label>SFTP host</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>gb/system_config_source_sftp</source_model>
    <sort_order>60</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</ftphost>
<ftpport translate="label">
     <label>SFTP port</label>
     <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
     <sort_order>70</sort_order>
     <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
     <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</ftpport>
```

Comment: And where is the code actually doing something?

Comment: it is showing select box and textbox. Now want to add onChange event on select box so that it will set value in textbox as given in example above.